# delete all the records from postgres where jsonb contains list of keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jpa, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete the records where jsonb have one or more keys.

My Data-

| id | jsonb_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[{"unit": "sale", "group": ["spares"]}]` |
| 2 | `[{"unit": "sale"}]` |
| 3 | `[{"member": "j1"}]` |

after deleting for key in (unit, group), my data should be like this-

| id | jsonb_col |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | `[{"member": "j1"}]` |

I have tried with cte query -

```
WITH keys AS (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, null) AS keys 
  FROM unnest(ARRAY['unit', 'group']) AS key
) 
DELETE FROM my_table 
WHERE jsonb_col @> (SELECT keys FROM keys)
```

this gives me DELETE 0.

where my select query alone returns below data-

```
{"unit": null, "group": null}
```

is there any other way to delete with list of keys in jsonb without cte?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an EXISTS subquery that iterates over the array elements and checks if one of them contains the keys

```
delete from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.jsonb_col) as x(item)
              where x.item ?| array['unit','group'])
```

Another option is to use a JSON path query

```
delete from the_table
where jsonb_col @? '$[*].keyvalue() ? (@.key == "unit" || @.key == "group")'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this query worked. But I want the same to be implemented in JPA repository, where I'm not allowed to use with placeholders (:col_name) or (?1) due to the ?| in the delete query. Getting - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jsonb_path_exists.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE temp TABLE test_mult_jsonb_keyt (
    id int,
    jsonb_col jsonb
) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO test_mult_jsonb_keyt
    VALUES (1, jsonb'[{"unit": "sale", "group": ["spares"]}]'),
    (2, '[{"unit": "sale"}]'),
    (3, '[{"member": "j1"}]');
DELETE FROM test_mult_jsonb_keyt
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(jsonb_col, '$[*].unit')
    OR jsonb_path_exists(jsonb_col, '$[*].group')
RETURNING
    *;
TABLE test_mult_jsonb_keyt;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the delete query worked as expected, is there any way I can use array object inside jsonb_path_exists? Need to implement the same with JPA repository. Thanks in advance.